# Xcode UI tests - Lost connection to test manager service

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

Sometimes while running my UI tests, I get the following error `Lost connection to test manager services`. No logs or anything. Happens randomly. I would provide more information but I just don't have it because of the nature of the error.

Using Xcode 7 beta 5.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm getting the same kind of error, even in the GM.

Comment: @Sid Nah, man. Tumbleweed. :( I just shortened up the tests so that it doesn't get to the point at which it usually breaks down.

Comment: Hey so hopefully this helps. In our case, it happened in a unit test class which we had for networking stuff. We used Nocilla for our tests. In our instance, we saw this happen because our network error test tested a cancelled request, followed by a timeout request. I think something's changed in request cancelation for iOS 9. In our case, I believe it happened because the stubbed request processed too fast, before our test case could cancel it. This wrecked the next test and led to this error. I know it's a long shot but I hope this helps. As of now we've removed the cancelation test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error appear for every async operations made in tests. It can be:

1. Operation on non existing object
2. `dispatch_after`
3. Network operations with wrongly assign block handler

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when running UI tests written in Swift. It turned out that the memory usage was increasing constantly when running a longer test (no memory release). When memory had been exhausted, the device "Lost connection to test manager services."

The solution? Using 'autoreleasepool' in its Swift version, in proper places.